# Difference in List initialization

Tags: c#

what is the difference between this to List initialization in C#:

```
List<int> list = [];
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

Are those two lines doing the exact same thing?

I can't find any source, web page, documentation mentioning it. Chat-GPT is insisting that first line will not work and is not correct, but it works for me.

Maybe there is a difference?

Comment: The first one is a very new feature in C# syntax. Both are correct and the same.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/daniel-white/836f5bf36cee831d49d1d2f259409f69

Comment: You could decompile this or look at the generated IL code and compare the differences.

Comment: The first one creates a singleton? See the Note here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0028?pivots=dotnet-8-0#overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<int> list1 = [];
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
```

Will be treated by the compiler as [the same thing](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBAGABAlAFgG5MEBmfJXAYVwG9Ndn9KFDcBZACgEoGmLIQBkoAZwAuAHlgSAfLgA24iSlwBeXAG0AuqQxCRKmTHlKV1TTACmAd1yjJJ+X31CAvpndA===). This is all just syntactic sugar.

The difference is when you change the type of the variable you're assigning it to.

```
IEnumerable<int> list = []; // [] is "Array.Empty<int>()"
ICollection<int> list = []; // [] is "new List<int>()"
HashSet<int> list = []; // [] is "new HashSet<int>()"
int[] list = []; // [] is "Array.Empty<int>()"
IReadOnlyList<int> list = []; // [] is "Array.Empty<int>()", and makes me chuckle
```

---

Now, if we're NOT talking about assigning an empty collection, then things get different.

```
List<int> list1 = [1,2,3];
List<int> list3 = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
```

[turns into](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBAGABAlAFgG5MEBmfJXAYVwG9Ndn9KFDcBZACgEoGmLIQBkoAZwAuAHlgSAfLgA24iSlwBeXAG0UAGiS7yAXVIYhIlTJjylKyppgBTAO65Rkq/L4M9B8gF9TIX9MfyA=)

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
CollectionsMarshal.SetCount(list, 3);
Span<int> span = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list);
int num = 0;
span[num] = 1;
num++;
span[num] = 2;
num++;
span[num] = 3;
num++;

List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
list2.Add(1);
list2.Add(2);
list2.Add(3);
```

When `[]` is assigned to an array, the compiled code will [still remain the same](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBAGABAlAFgG5MEBmfJXAYVwG9Ndn9KFDcBZACgEoGmLIbAAuAbQC6uADYcAvLjEoANEmXkJpDEOExxU6QFZcCmAFMA7rlGSGKteQC+WoY8yOgA==). There will be differences under the hood depending on the target type, even if `[]` is treated as an array. Use https://sharplab.io (or another decompiler) to find out what really happens in your situation.