Will the C# compiler optimize away the re-evaluation of expression-bodied members?
If I write the following for a class member definition:
public List<string> Names => new() {
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Baz"
};

... my understanding is that the expression gets evaluated every time the member is accessed, so a new instance of List<string> will get created each time.  Will the C# compiler optimize this away and create just one instance that gets accessed each time?  If not, does using the following collection expression make any difference?
public List<string> Names => [
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Baz"
];

And if not, how can I get this kind of class member giving me a list of values which doesn't result in a new class being initialized each time it's accessed?

You can use public List<string> Names {get;} = ...;.

You could do this:
public List<string> Names { get; } = new() {
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Baz"
};

...or using a collection expression:
public List<string> Names { get; } = [
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Baz"
];

This will create an automatic get-only property, assigning the value only once, when the class is instantiated.
If this is in fact a static list, you might as well make it "static":
private static readonly List<string> _names = [
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Baz"
];

public IReadOnlyList<string> Names => _names;

I changed the public type to IReadOnlyList to avoid mutation. You might also consider using FrozenSet for this case.
Pro tip: A great way to see what your code will actually do on a lower level is sharplab.io

"You can change the latter to", I mean, you can change either of them to auto properties. They'll behave the same in regard to how often the list is computed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77970135/1043380

@gunr2171 You are correct, but my example is using a collection expression, which would correspond to his 2nd example.
